# .each not working to separate sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to create a number field (.item_adults) that multiply it self and print the value into a class="item_price". To do that I create some of this:

```
<div class="bookSection">
  <input class="item_adults" name="adults" type="number" data-price="10" value="1" maxlength="2" min="0">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span class="item_price">10</span></p>
</div>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".bookSection").each(function() {
        $(".item_adults").change(function(){
            var price = ($(this).val());
            var ammount = ($(this).attr("data-price"));
            var total = (price) * ammount;
            $(".item_price").html(total);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bookSection">
  <input class="item_adults" name="adults" type="number" data-price="10" value="1" maxlength="2" min="0">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span class="item_price">10</span></p>
</div>
  
<div class="bookSection">
  <input class="item_adults" name="adults" type="number" data-price="15" value="1" maxlength="2" min="0">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span class="item_price">15</span></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and I'm using:

```
$(".bookSection").each(function() {
```

to try to separate it in sections to work independently modifying its own .item_price, but right now one section is affecting the other ones.

hope the explanation is clear, Thank you!

Comment: It's best to include your code example here, in Stack Overflow, rather than linking to external resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the instances within each section using `find()`

```
$(".bookSection").each(function() {
    var $item_price = $(this).find(".item_price")
    $(this).find(".item_adults").change(function(){
        var price = ($(this).val());
        var ammount = ($(this).attr("data-price"));
        var total = (price) * ammount;
        $item_price.html(total);
    });
});
```

Could also simplfy this without needing the `each` on the sections:

```
$(".item_adults").change(function(){
        var price = ($(this).val());
        var ammount = ($(this).attr("data-price"));
        var total = (price) * ammount;
        $(this).closest(".bookSection").find(".item_price").html(total);
});
```

Comment: probably best to set `$(this)` as a var too if you are using it multiple times

Comment: @Pete agrree that is best practice

Answer (score 2):

Close, only a couple small changes. When you reference $(".item_adults") and $(".item_price"), it affects them all. Limit the scope to the CURRENT .bookSection, as below:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".bookSection").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".item_adults").change(function(){
            var price = ($(this).val());
            var ammount = ($(this).attr("data-price"));
            var total = (price) * ammount;
            $(this).parents(".bookSection").find(".item_price").html(total);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bookSection">
  <input class="item_adults" name="adults" type="number" data-price="10" value="1" maxlength="2" min="0">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span class="item_price">10</span></p>
</div>
  
<div class="bookSection">
  <input class="item_adults" name="adults" type="number" data-price="15" value="1" maxlength="2" min="0">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span class="item_price">15</span></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```